# which sounds more natural? 我今天已经把猫食放了 or 我已经今天把猫食放了

Tags: word-order

我今天已经把猫食放了 wǒ *jīntiān* **yǐjīng** bǎ māoshí fàng le

vs

我已经今天把猫食放了 wǒ **yǐjīng** *jīntiān* bǎ māoshí fàng le

(if it matters, the context is that every day the cat should be fed once, and the husband is informing his wife that the cat has already gotten their food for today)

I've checked my standard resources like [ChineseGrammarWiki](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22already%22_with_%22yijing%22), but they don't address this point.

---

I'll accept answers to the main question above, but as a subsidiary question: if this were in speech, would it it fine to say

我今天已经把猫食**给**放了 ／ 我已经今天把猫食**给**放了?

(i.e. adding 给 gěi for emphasis)

Comment: search site for previous Q&A about order of adverbs/adverbials, accordingly time adverbials come first (unless there is a special emphasis on one particular adverb), i.e. top choice agrees with grammar, see https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/12197/the-word-order-of-co-existing-adverbs-in-a-sentence

Comment: in English you can hear "already today", remarkably submitting "already today" (w/o any verb)  to iciba yields 今天已经

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is definitely natural, and moreover, the second is not only unnatural, it is not grammatically correct.

You would put 已经 in front of a time period when an action is happening, for example

> 我已经三年没回家了

However, in your sentence, 今天 is the time point when you did something, therefore you would like to put 已经 after it.

For your subsidiary question, it is still the first one that is correct, which is

> 我今天已经把猫食给放了

Answer (score 1):

我今天已经把猫食放了 is the right sentence.

我 把 猫食 放了 I set the cat's food.

今天我已经把猫食给放了 or 我今天已经把猫食放了 is all natual.

Answer (score -1):

“已经”：Adverbs.It means that something has been done or time has passed.

Answer (score -2):

我今天已经放了猫粮了 sounds more natural.